# Question on Sierpinski's theorem, why $f_1,f_2$ are well defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm reading the following [post](http://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/sierpinskis-theorem/) and I have a question that I cannot resolve:

Why are the function $f_1$ and $f_2$ are well defined? In other words: why $m(r)\cap n(r)=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{A}$ is a bijection so $\mathcal{A}_1 = g((-\infty, 0))$ and $\mathcal{A}_2 = g([0, \infty))$ are disjoint. As $m : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{A}_1$ and $n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{A}_2$, $m(r) \in \mathcal{A_1}$ and $n(r) \in {A_2}$. Now $\mathcal{A} = \{[x] \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $[x] = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid x - y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Note that any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is in a unique equivalence class, namely $[t]$. As $\mathcal{A}_1$, $\mathcal{A}_2$ are disjoint and $\mathcal{A}_1\cup\mathcal{A}_2 = \mathcal{A}$, $[t]$ is an element of precisely one of $\mathcal{A}_1$, $\mathcal{A}_2$. So either there is $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(r) = [t]$ or $n(r) = [t]$, but not both.

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: A Small question: is it right saying that ${\mathcal{A}}_1 = \{[x] \mid x \in (-\infty,0)\}$?

Comment: No, $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary bijection (it is not $t \mapsto [t]$ as this is not injective). Instead, $\mathcal{A}_1 = \{[x] \mid g^{-1}([x]) \in (-\infty, 0)\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much and Happy Holidays!